# Filter replacing one instance of the function but not the other

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to php and am using the following code from http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/ to replace the `the_excerpt()` calls:

```
function improved_trim_excerpt($text) {
    global $post;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content('');
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace('\]\]\>', ']]&gt;', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', '', $text);
        $text = strip_tags($text, '<p>');
        $excerpt_length = 80;
        $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
        if (count($words)> $excerpt_length) {
            array_pop($words);
            array_push($words, '[...]');
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'improved_trim_excerpt');
```

I am using the [Brandford Magazine 3.0 theme](http://www.der-prinz.com/branfordmagazine-wordpress-magazine-style-theme/), and have two instances of `the_excerpt()` calls in my code.

Somehow the first call is getting replaced correctly and is displaying the text correctly as expected using `improved_trim_excerpt`, but the other call still uses the old `the_excerpt()` functionality.

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `the_excerpt` anywhere... but I'm guessing you're referring to the `preg_replace`? If so, try adding the `g` flag at the end of your regex. This turns on global mode, so the regex will match multiple times.

Comment: `the_excerpt` is the function which this new function is trying to improve upon. See the title of the blog post I linked to.